# What is the recommended way to run a react app and a node js backend in the same container using cloud run

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I would like to containerize a react app and node js backend API, that's currently running on a GCE VM. The majority of the information that's available online leads me to believe that I need to deploy them as separate containers to Cloud Run. However as Martin points out in the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHH7eQLbG_s - Simplify your web apps on Google Cloud Run, that one could you use Cloud Run itself.

Is this possible and if so, is there any info. available online relating to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run can export only one port. Therefore, if you want to expose 2 different things (i.e. the frontend and the backend), you need to have a unique entrypoint.

You can wrap your static pages in your NodeJS backend server, or package, in your container, a NGINX server that will route to the react app the request to the static content, and to the nodeJS backend, the backend request.

---

About the Martin's video, you can also read my comments. It's better to deploy 2 different stuffs and to put a Load Balancer in front of both (similar to your NGINX in fact, but decoupled and therefore more scalable and easier to update). I personally recommend App Engine Standard for the static content (because serving that content is processing free, and the cheapest!), and cloud run for the backend.

Comment: The reason I'm leaning towards Cloud Run for the React app is that I need to use VPC-SC to make the app only runs inside the corporate network and VPC-SC support AFAIK is not avail. for AppEngine. I've managed to get both running inside the same container with the help of Martin's video and will post the code here for reference.

Comment: you want an access from your corporate network. Are all the user on Google Workspace with a Google Account??